# Linking Boost::system library with OpenNI makefile

Tags: c++, boost, makefile, boost-asio, openni

I'm trying to use the C++ Boost library to write some depth data I get form my Kinect to the serial port. In order to do this I need to link the appropriate libraries with this pre-written Makefile. I wrote a basic program using boost/asio to get a feel for the libraries and in order to compile I had to link to the boost_system library located in /usr/local/lib and include the header files from /usr/local/include/boost. I figured to use it in my OpenNI code I'd just have to make the same connection from this Makefile instead.

```mk
    # take this file's dir
    COMMON_CPP_MAKE_FILE_DIR = $(dir $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))

    include $(COMMON_CPP_MAKE_FILE_DIR)CommonDefs.mak

    # define a function to figure .o file for each source file (placed under intermediate directory)
    SRC_TO_OBJ = $(addprefix ./$(INT_DIR)/,$(addsuffix .o,$(notdir $(basename $1))))

    # create a list of all object files
    OBJ_FILES = $(call SRC_TO_OBJ,$(SRC_FILES_LIST))

    # define a function to translate any source file to its dependency file (note that the way we create
    # dep files, as a side affect of compilation, always puts the files in the INT_DIR with suffix .d)
    SRC_TO_DEP = $(addprefix ./$(INT_DIR)/,$(addsuffix .d,$(notdir $(basename $1))))

    # create a list of all dependency files
    DEP_FILES = $(call SRC_TO_DEP,$(SRC_FILES_LIST))

    # older version of gcc doesn't support the '=' symbol in include dirs, so we replace it ourselves with sysroot
    INC_DIRS_FROM_SYSROOT = $(patsubst =/%,$(TARGET_SYS_ROOT)/%,$(INC_DIRS))

    # append the -I switch to each include directory
    INC_DIRS_OPTION = $(foreach dir,$(INC_DIRS_FROM_SYSROOT),-I$(dir)) -I/usr/local/include/boost

    # append the -L switch to each library directory
    LIB_DIRS_OPTION = $(foreach dir,$(LIB_DIRS),-L$(dir)) -L$(OUT_DIR) -L/usr/local/lib 

    # append the -l switch to each library used
    USED_LIBS_OPTION = $(foreach lib,$(USED_LIBS),-l$(lib)) -lboost_system

    # append the -D switch to each define
    DEFINES_OPTION = $(foreach def,$(DEFINES),-D$(def))

    # tell compiler to use the target system root
    ifdef TARGET_SYS_ROOT
        CFLAGS += --sysroot=$(TARGET_SYS_ROOT)
        LDFLAGS += --sysroot=$(TARGET_SYS_ROOT)
    endif

    # set Debug / Release flags
    ifeq "$(CFG)" "Debug"
        CFLAGS += -O0 -g
    endif
    ifeq "$(CFG)" "Release"
        CFLAGS += -O2 -DNDEBUG
    endif

    CFLAGS += $(INC_DIRS_OPTION) $(DEFINES_OPTION)
    LDFLAGS += $(LIB_DIRS_OPTION) $(USED_LIBS_OPTION)

    # some lib / exe specifics
    ifneq "$(LIB_NAME)" ""
        OUTPUT_NAME = lib$(LIB_NAME).so
        CFLAGS += -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden
        ifneq ("$(OSTYPE)","Darwin")
            LDFLAGS += -Wl,--no-undefined
            OUTPUT_NAME = lib$(LIB_NAME).so
            OUTPUT_COMMAND = $(CXX) -o $(OUTPUT_FILE) $(OBJ_FILES) $(LDFLAGS) -shared
        else
            LDFLAGS += -undefined error
            OUTPUT_NAME = lib$(LIB_NAME).dylib
            OUTPUT_COMMAND = $(CXX) -o $(OUTPUT_FILE) $(OBJ_FILES) $(LDFLAGS) -dynamiclib -headerpad_max_install_names
        endif
    endif
    ifneq "$(EXE_NAME)" ""
        OUTPUT_NAME = $(EXE_NAME)
        OUTPUT_COMMAND = $(CXX) -o $(OUTPUT_FILE) $(OBJ_FILES) $(LDFLAGS)
    endif
    ifneq "$(SLIB_NAME)" ""
        CFLAGS += -fPIC
        OUTPUT_NAME = lib$(SLIB_NAME).a
        OUTPUT_COMMAND = $(AR) -cq $(OUTPUT_FILE) $(OBJ_FILES)
    endif

    define CREATE_SRC_TARGETS
    # create a target for the object file (the CXX command creates both an .o file
    # and a .d file)
    ifneq ("$(OSTYPE)","Darwin")
    $(call SRC_TO_OBJ,$1) : $1 | $(INT_DIR)
        $(CXX) -MD -MP -MT "$(call SRC_TO_DEP,$1) $$@" -c $(CFLAGS) -o $$@ $$<
    else
    $(call SRC_TO_OBJ,$1) : $1 | $(INT_DIR)
        $(CXX) -c $(CFLAGS) -o $$@ $$<
    endif
    endef

    #############################################################################
    # Targets
    #############################################################################
    .PHONY: clean-objs clean-defs

    include $(COMMON_CPP_MAKE_FILE_DIR)CommonTargets.mak

    # create targets for each source file
    $(foreach src,$(SRC_FILES_LIST),$(eval $(call CREATE_SRC_TARGETS,$(src))))

    # include all dependency files (we don't need them the first time, so we can use -include)
    -include $(DEP_FILES)

    $(OUTPUT_FILE): $(OBJ_FILES)
        $(OUTPUT_COMMAND)

    clean-objs:
        rm -rf $(OBJ_FILES)

    clean-defs:
        rm -rf $(DEP_FILES)

    clean: clean-objs clean-defs
```

I added:

```
-I/usr/local/include/boost
```

to the INC_DIRS_OPTION

```
-L/usr/local/lib
```

to the LIBS_DIRS_OPTION, and

```
-lboost_system
```

to the USED_LIBS_OPTION (asio relies on the boost system library for error generation of some sort)

I get this error:

```
c++ -o ../Bin/x64-Release/Sample-NiSimpleRead ./x64-Release/NiSimpleRead.o -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -L../../Lib -L../Bin/x64-Release  -lOpenNI -lboost_system 
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libboost_system.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "boost::system::generic_category()", referenced from:
      __GLOBAL__I_a in NiSimpleRead.o
  "boost::system::system_category()", referenced from:
      __GLOBAL__I_a in NiSimpleRead.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [../Bin/x64-Release/Sample-NiSimpleRead] Error 1
```

I've tried adding the lib directory to my DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH which did nothing. I've also tried creating some kind of shared (*.so) library, first using the NiSimpleRead.o binary combined with the libboost_system.a file, which brought up a lot of errors. Then tried changing the boost_system.a file by itself, to a .so, which also did nothing.  Any advice on this would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that you have only 64-bit Boost, and you're trying to make an universal (both 32-bit and 64-bit) binary. Make sure to install dependencies in both 32-bit and 64-bit versions, or throw away this `-arch i386` from your build instructions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply! I'm not really sure how to go about either of those things, I can't find 32-bit dependencies for boost nor can I figure how to remove the -arch i386 from the build instructions, where would that be in the make?

Comment: I switched everything over to my 32 bit Ubuntu 11.04 laptop and installed Boost and everything compiled fine. So it was a matter of having the right dependencies. Cheers